# Are there any conventions for keeping page object modules/concerns in a certain location?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am refactoring some system tests, and using page objects to keep things dry.

A couple of page objects have become quite large, and are good candidates for further refactoring into concerns/ modules.

Rails has conventions when concerns are used elsewhere. For example, model or controller concerns are all autoloaded.

In my page objects I'm having to require each module manually. Am I overlooking any conventions, or does the page object pattern need to be set up manually?

My page objects look something like this

```
# spec/support/pages/my_page.rb


# is there a convention to locate these files somewhere that is autoloaded by Rails? 
# or do I need to require these manually? 
require './spec/support/pages/concerns/first_concern'
require './spec/support/pages/concerns/second_concern'

module Page 
  class MyPage
    include FirstConcern
    include SecondConcern
    
    def do_some_things_on_my_page
      # some things ....
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Page objects aren't exactly a Rails concept, so there's not really any official guidance on them.  As a Rails dev, your choice of `spec/support/pages` seems very reasonable to me (and as close to convention as you'll get).  Regardless of the location you won't get auto-loading for those files.  You could edit your `spec/rails_helper.rb` and add some variation of:

```rb
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/pages/concerns/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/pages/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
```

In past projects I've used the site-prism gem and put them into `spec/page_objects/pages` and `spec/page_objects/sections`.  With site-prism you need sections imported first so pages can use them.  (Note: If sections depend on other sections you may need a few requires or a more complex configuration)

```rb
# rails_helper.rb
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/page_objects/sections/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/page_objects/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
```